# How to specify certain method on component from route file in angular 2 & 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, laravel, typescript, angular-ui-router

I have been searching for certain feature we use in Laravel to specify where the routes will go in controllers methods like so:

```
Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');
```

In above code when user navigate to `/user` the app will send him to the UserController and directly into index method.

I'm looking for something similar to help me handle delete routes because I want to restrict them for super admins only and don't want to write additional component for that

Answer (score 1):

You need to [use middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes) for that. For example:

```
Route::get('user/{id}/delete', 'UserController@delete')->middleware('superadmin');
```

Comment: i think he is asking for a feature similar to what is there in larvel in angular, i might be wrong in understanding though

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not possible directly with Angular where as you can do this

Send some data with the router like

```
{path : 'heroes', component : HeroDetailComponent, data : {some_data : 'some value'}}
```

> And in the component onInit check for the data using ActivatedRoute
>   and assign it to the proper method of the compoenent

**Update**

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route
      .data
      .subscribe(v => console.log(v));
  }
```

Comment: would you mind show me some code on how to assign the data to the component's method?  @rahul-singh